# How would i model this in Core-Data

Tags: ios, core-data

Imagine a singles tennis match...

With the entities:

Match

Player

Game

Set

A match will need two players, but will also contain any number of sets, which in turn can contain any number of games. What would the relationships / inverse look like?

Comment: JonnyKnowsBest...You know the Best...So first share what have you created. Only then we can suggest you.

Comment: I never said i had created anything. I'm trying to get my head around modelling a particular situation using Core Data.

Comment: You already thought through it better than anyone else, try to setup something in Core Data and see if it works. If you're having issues, then you can come back for specific advice as @AnoopVaidya pointed out.

Comment: I think you just described the relationships in your last paragraph.